# nawk/awk: How to present an error message while there is no string match?

Tags: awk, match, nawk

I'll start by saying that this forum is an excellent source of knowledge.
I need your help in presenting No Match error message.

```
printf "some\nwhere\nonly\nwe\nknow\n" > test.txt
```

I'm looking for 'only' string and if there is a match, it will be presented

```
nawk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=0 a=0 s="only" test.txt | awk '{if ($0 ~ /only/) print; else print "No Match"}'
```

Output: only

If I'm looking for 'only' string and checking if there is also apple on this line, I'll get No match message

```
nawk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=0 a=0 s="only" test.txt | awk '{if ($0 ~ /apple/) print; else print "No Match"}'
```

Output: No Match

BUT if I'm looking for 'apple' string (there is no such) and check if it's there, I don't get 'No Match' message.

```
nawk 'c-->0;$0~s{if(b)for(c=b+1;c>1;c--)print r[(NR-c+1)%b];print;c=a}b{r[NR%b]=$0}' b=0 a=0 s="apple" test.txt | awk '{if ($0 ~ /apple/) print; else print "No Match"}'
```

The output is blank.
How can I change this behaviour, I want to get 'No Match' message.

Comment: The `nawk` is not producing any output, because you never enter the first block of action statements since no lines match `s` and you never enter the second because `b` is zero.  The awk has no input to work with, so it exits without doing anything.  What are you trying to do with the first `nawk` command?

Comment: This is only a simple example, in practice I use nawk to capture multiple lines (a & b != 0)and parse it afterwards. The issue is that even if a & b !=0 and there is no match, I couldn't define an action about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in awk.

If the searchphrase isn't found at all.

```
awk '/searchphrase/{c++} END{if(c == 0) print "No Match"}' file
```

If you want to print no match for every line without a match.

```
awk '!/searchphrase/{print "No Match"}' file
```

If you want to still print searchphrase when found

```
awk '/searchphrase/{c++; print} END{if(c == 0) print "No Match"}' file
```

Comment: Jidder, I'm interested in passing the original information on in case c !=0 but failed to do so. Do you know why the following doesn't work:
awk '/only/{c++} END{if(c == 0) print "No Match"; else print}'

Comment: its in the END Statement which is only executed after all lines have been processed, ive ammended my answer.